# Change grouping based on parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, grouping

My intangible asset needs to be grouped based on parameters. The end user will pick one of two options: *Roll Forward* or *Book vs. Tax*. These allow the user to toggle between two views based on how they want the data presented.

When *Roll Forward* is selected the report should group like this:

> - Company
>
>   - Amortizable/Unamortizable Assets
>
>     - Deductible/Non-deductible Assets
>
>       - Intangible type

When *Book vs. Tax* is selected:

> - Company
>
>   - Intangible type
>
>     - Location

My understanding is that I am trying to use dynamic grouping. Is there a way to get this behavior into the report?

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to make two Subreports, one for each parameter. Design each subreport to display your data and group based on the above structure. Then place them both into their own section. (I put them in Report Footers for this example:)

[image]

Then set the Report Footers to Suppress based on what parameter is submitted. For example, Report Footer A would use this code in the Suppress section:

```
{?MyParameter} <> "Roll Forward"
```